# performing a thread using jcomponets

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, jcomponent

am back again!. i have a probrem here. am making uneditable jcombobox. i have a list of items in it("crus","davy","shawn") and i want if someone clicks on crus, a thread of images with a Thread.sleep of 2 seconds will appear at a jlabel called picturelabel. when i try to put method run() inside method actionperformed, i get "illegal start of expression". i also get an error "not a statement" when i try to create an array of imageicon.

```
public class Myjcombobox extends JFrame implements ActionListener,Runnable {
JComboBox job;
String[] items={"crus","shawn","davy","others"};
JLabel picturelabel;
public Myjcombobox(){
super("oh mymy");
setSize(1000,1000);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
BorderLayout border=new BorderLayout();
setLayout(border);
job=new JComboBox(items);
job.addActionListener(this);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
JComboBox combo=(JComboBox)event.getSource();
String name=(String)combo.getSelectedItem();
if(name=="crus"){
 public void run(){//i get an error illegal start of expression//
 JImageIcon[] crusimages= new JImageIcon{"crus reading.jpg","crus playing.jpg","crus in class.jpg"}; //i get an error "not a statement","( or[ expected"//  
 }   
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Myjcombobox jcomb=new Myjcombobox();


}
```

Comment: Read more about Basic of JAVA.

Comment: is the God's blessing dependent on somebody providing the right answer, or sort of a general bonus to anyone reading?

Comment: @fdreger no need to be facetious.

Comment: @fdreger stop being like that men, am just seeking for help. how can you help me?

Comment: @gikarasojokinene: if I could help you by writing an answer, I would (seriously). But I strongly feel that you took up a task much too big for your current level and should begin with something simpler, and then work your way up from there. Any help I could give would be - basically - rewriting a whole Java book for you. And since - for some reasons - you were not able to use the abundance of resources available online, there is no reason to think that you would be able to use my answer.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I was not trying to by, sorry if you felt offended. I was surprised at the presence of divine's providence in a question about Java, that's all. Do you think I should remove my original comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(name=="crus"){

{//i get an error illegal start of expression//
 public void run()

//i get an error "not a statement","( or[ expected"//  
 JImageIcon[] crusimages= new JImageIcon{"crus reading.jpg","crus playing.jpg","crus in class.jpg"}; 
 }
```

Every statement in the above code has a problem:

```
 if(name=="crus"){
```

Don't use "==" to compare strings. Instead you should be using the `equals(...)` method:

```
if ("crus".equals(name));
```

Next, you can't just define a run() method in the middle of your code.

```
public void run()
```

The run() method belongs to a Thread, so you need to create a Thread and override the run() method. Something like:

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("I'm a Thread");
    }
};
thread.start();
```

Finallay you can't create an Array of Image Icons in one step like this:

```
JImageIcon[] crusimages= new JImageIcon{"crus reading.jpg","crus playing.jpg","crus in class.jpg"};
```

You need to create an empty Array and then add the Icons one at a time:

```
ImageIcon[] crusImages = new new ImageIcon[3];
crusImage[0] = new ImageIcon( "crus reading.jpg" );
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you very very much. i finally did it with your help!!!!!. God bless you men

Answer (score 0):

You can't just run() the thread, if you want to start it for the first time, you must use the method start(), witch starts a thread and runs the run() method. If you use just the run(), you won't be creating a thread, for it will run on the current thread.

Java Concurrency tutorial from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html.

Java Swing Components from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html.

I hop I could help.

Saclyr.

Comment: thanks for reminding me that. i will add Thread.start inside the public static void main(i.e (Thread(new Myjcombobox())).start(); but is there anyway i can call the method run() inside the if loop? how can i make it work

Comment: Once the method run() returns, the thread dies (unless is a daemon thread), so you have to create some kind of while loop (or do-while) to keep the thread alive, and Use methods to pause(wait()), sleep(sleep()) and "resume"(notify()).

And by the way, for the concurrency tutorial, use this link, is better: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: And I miswrote the link of "Java Swing Components from Oracle". Use this one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html

If you seek other tutorials, go to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/